# Pointers,structure C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure, alloc

How can I work with the structure if i pass structure like parameter function ** ?

```
typedef struct TQueue
{
    ...
    int m_Len;
}TQUEUE;

void nahraj(TQUEUE **tmp)
{
    tmp[5]->m_Len = 7;
}

int main (void)
{
    TQUEUE *tmp;
    tmp = malloc(10*sizeof(*tmp));
    nahraj (&tmp);
    printf("%d\n",tmp[5].m_Len);
}
```

Comment: Does the code you've posted work? If not, how not?

Comment: Usually if a function takes `TQUEUE **` parameter, it's because the function is expected to allocate the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference `tmp` before indexing it, since it's a pointer to an array, not an array itself.

And the elements of the array are structures, not pointers to structures, so you use `.` rather than `->`.

```
void nahraj(TQUEUE **tmp)
{
    (*tmp)[5].m_Len = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should be declared like

```
void nahraj(TQUEUE *tmp, size_t i, int value )
{
    tmp[i]->m_Len = value;
}
```

and called like

```
nahraj( tmp, 5, 7 );
```

There is no sense to pass the pointer `tmp` by reference to the function (through a pointer to the pointer `tmp`) because the original pointer is not changed within the function.

As for your function definition then at least you need to write within the function

```
( *tmp )[5]->m_Len = 7;
```

Otherwise the function will invoke undefined behavior because this expression `tmp[5]`  within the function means that the pointer `tmp` points to an array of pointers to objects of the type `TQUEUE`. But this is not true.